# MouseEnter and MouseLeave Event not raising in user control

Tags: c#, picturebox, mouseenter

Here is the problem:

- I have a simple c# form
- I have a simple c# user control containing a picturebox and other button.
- My form contains one instance of the user control.
- I want that when the user do a mouseEnter in the picture box, the mouse cursor change and when the user do a mouseLeave of the picturebox, the mouse go back to normal.

What is happening now is that the events are not fired at all. I put break point into MouseOver, MouseEnter, MouseMove, MouseLeave, etc and none of thems fired. It's the first time I have this problem in C#.

I think it has something to do with the "routed event" but I can't figure it out. If there is another way to achieve what I'm doing, this will also be considered a solution. What is important is that at the end, the user control will be the master of the mouse cursor over his "territory".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What events are you using? The `UserController.MouseEnter` and `UserController.MouseLeave` events or the `PictureBox.MouseEnter` and `PictureBox.MouseLeave` events?

You should use the latter as the `PictureBox` will handle the event if the mouse enters the user controller directly through the `PictureBox`.

Comment: Yeah I used PictureBox.MouveEnter events and in fact, it was working. My problem was that I had 2 picture box and one of them was over the other. Very newbie error!

Answer (score 1):

As InBetween wrote, `PictureBox.MouseXXX` should be firing. You can trap those in your `UserControl`.

If you want the event to be fired on behalf of `UserControl`, just disable the `PictureBox`. Be aware though that the event would fire for any mouse position over the UserContrl, not only the PictureBox.

Comment: Thanks for the input, see my comment in the other answer. :)